# track Facebook Share traffic

Tags: facebook, share

```
 $("document").ready(function(){

FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(href, widget) {

...do something
});

});
```

the above code track the user LIKE the site, how to track if the user SHARE the site?

Answer (score 0):

Please note that "Share" has been deprecated in favor of the like button (see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/share/).  The like button has a "Send" component which is basically the equivalent of Share.

Unfortunately, even Send is known to suffer from the problem you describe: It doesn't generate any sort of confirmation or callback.  This problem has been reported to Facebook and you can track the bug report here:
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/275748669167650